# {align} gives "erroneous nesting" and I can't compile the document

Tags: equations, align

I'm trying to make some equations aligned underneath each other. With a second column on the right with comments (for some lines). I keep getting "erroneous nesting" error and can't compile, but I can't find the error.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
  & \Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) = A\sin \left( \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} (x - \upsilon t) \right) && \\
  & \Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) = A\sin \left( k (x - \upsilon t) \right)                    && \text{substitute}\ \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\ \text{with k} \\
  & \Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) = A\sin \left( kx - k\upsilon t \right)                      && \\
  & \Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) = A\sin \left( kx - \frac{2\pi}{\textcolor{red}{\lambda}} \textcolor{red}{\lambda} f t \right)
                                                                                        && 2\pi f = \omega \\
  & \Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) = A\sin ( kx - \omega t + \varphi )                          && \text{and} \varphi \text{we just add because} \\
\end{align}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome! You cannot have an `align` environment in an `equation` environment. You could use an `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align`, `align*`, `gather`, `gather*`, `multline`, and `multline*` are standalone multi-line equation environments and can therefore not be nested within each other or within an `equation` or `equation*` environment.

Your code compiles if you simply get rid of the `equation` wrapper.

On the other hand, if you want the five equations to be associated with a *single* equation number, you should replace `\begin{align}` with `\begin{aligned}[b]` and `\end{align}` with `\end{aligned}`.

And, don't overuse `\left` and `\right` to auto-size parentheses. Explicit sizing often works much better.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}[b]
\Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) &= A\sin \Bigl( \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} (x - \upsilon t) \Bigr) \\
\Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) &= A\sin \bigl( k (x - \upsilon t) \bigr)   
                          && \text{substitute $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ with $k$} \\
\Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) &= A\sin ( kx - k\upsilon t) \\
\Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) &= A\sin \Bigl( kx - \frac{2\pi}{\textcolor{red}{\lambda}} 
                          \textcolor{red}{\lambda} f t\Bigr)       
                          && 2\pi f = \omega \\
\Leftrightarrow Y(x,t) &= A\sin ( kx - \omega t + \varphi )        
                          && \text{and $\varphi$ we just add because}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```